# How to inject port and host using ENV variable in Create React App Proxy settings?

Tags: reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

Is it possible to set proxy settings in CRA differently than with package.json? For example using ENV variables?

From CRA [docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) it states

> Use environment variables to inject the right server host and port into your app.

Is this sentence about proxy or dev server itself?

According to the [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/2e82ebb3371731a5c4e346f310848ddb23fd0976/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L266) and [this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/2e82ebb3371731a5c4e346f310848ddb23fd0976/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L69), the only way to influence proxy settings is via package.json.

Comment: I too am looking for something similar, did you managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 17):

> Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher.

You can manually configure proxy now. You need to install `http-proxy-middleware` first.

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
```

Then create a file `src/setupProxy.js` with following content.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api', // You can pass in an array too eg. ['/api', '/another/path']
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

You can add proxy now in the `.env` file, remember you need the `REACT_APP_` prefix for development server to pick up the environment variable.

```
REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST=http://localhost:5000
```

Ref: [Proxy manually](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually)

Comment: This is the way

Comment: It works. Indeed in the .env file you have to define the variable with the `REACT_APP_` prefix - but when you use anywhere don't write the prefix. Therefore `target: process.env.PROXY_HOST,`

Answer (score 12):

### Regarding:

> Use environment variables to inject the right server host and port
> into your app.

This refers to neither the proxy server nor the dev server. This is a recommendation on how to handle per-environment server settings if `proxy` does not provide enough flexibility for you (i.e. if you need to use protocols other than `http`, `https`, or `ws`). For example, if you have an api call within your code, you can use an environment variable to do something like this:

```
axios(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + endpoint, options).then(data=>{ console.dir(data); })
```

Where each environment has it's own definition of `REACT_APP_BASE_URL`.

---

### Without `package.json`:

It is not possible to influence proxy settings without modifying `package.json`.

See [Configuring the Proxy Manually (CRA docs)](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuring-the-proxy-manually)

`package.json` is the only documented way to influence proxy settings.

You can also see [line 96 of CRA's `start.js`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/19e0bb1881e24fb1ee3fe421413d4d87e67f68dd/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L96). This implementation leaves absolutely no ability to use ENV vars to inject the host/port to CRA's proxy settings.

This is really one of the reasons I detest CRA, to be honest. All of this behavior is so very easily handled when not bound by the limitations of CRA.

---

### [You could just eject create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject):

`npm run eject`

All of these problems will go away instantly... The `start.js` script referenced above is a bit of the code that is ejected. So you would very easily be able to replace those proxy settings with ENV vars.

Just be certain to create a checkpoint for yourself prior to doing this as there is no reverting an ejection.

However--if you must stick with CRA--you **CAN** very easily modify `package.json` using environment variables.

---

### How to inject ENV vars into `package.json` at build time:

This is essentially what CRA does with the `REACT_APP_` env vars (though it directly injects them into `process.env`).

`package.json` is just a big JSON object, so all you need to do is parse it on the server side right before you deploy, update the `"proxy"` value to the ones provided by your ENV vars, save the file, and then run your build/deploy.

Here is a very simple example of how to achieve this, you just need to run this script *before* deployment in a context where you still have access to `process.env`:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// read/process package.json
const file = './package.json';
let pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file).toString());

// at this point you should have access to your ENV vars
pkg.proxy = `${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}`;

// the 2 enables pretty-printing and defines the number of spaces to use
fs.writeFileSync(pkg, JSON.stringify(file, null, 2));
```

I know this doesn't explicitly answer the question of how to handle this "without package.json", but I don't think that's the necessary approach anyways.

Further, this **DOES** asnswer the *title* question of "How to inject port and host using ENV variable in Create React App Proxy settings?"

Comment: How would you pass env variables to the package file?

Comment: Was this downvoted because you didn't understand the answer? That's rather inconsiderate... You should really comment first and ask for clarification. This is a trivial procedure with Node.JS. I will update my answer shortly with an example.

Comment: Sorry that your answer was down-voted with no explanation or comment provided. But I am glad that you are realizing that you are not answering the question, or at least not providing an optimal solution.

Comment: Agreed, I am not answering the exact question of "Is this sentence about proxy or dev server itself?". But why, if such a limitation exists, is this extremely simple workaround not an optimal solution? Please also note that this does indeed answer the **title** question of "How to inject port and host using ENV variable in Create React App Proxy settings?"

Comment: No problem and actually, thank you for the critique. You've forced me to reevaluate my answer and provide much more detail!

Comment: @JonnyAsmar you have added exactly what I mentioned in my answer and in comment section with brandNew.

Comment: @cauchy Not quite... you provided a suggestion on how to use the `REACT_APP_` env vars. My addition here was simply an explanation of why & when CRA would recommend that. Your answer, however, doesn't specifically answer the title question of how to use ENV vars to influence proxy settings. Using env vars is not proxying. It is simply defining a per-environment URL to use. This is a completely different mechanism.

Comment: @JonnyAsmar your answer much clear now and I see the difference between your and my answer thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Your workaround for pre-processing `package.json` is not really what I was looking for, but your explanation about how to interpret the "Use environment variables to inject the right server host and port into your app." sentence was helpful; I think both the OP and I misunderstood it to mean you could inject the proxy setting into CRA via an environment variable.

Comment: Hmm, can you help me better understand what exactly you are looking for? CRAs "proxy" settings are defined in `package.json`. This is where they're read from and interpreted, so this may be the only way. Perhaps you can provide some pseudo-code or something of what you need to be able to do?

Comment: I've updated the first part of my answer with a reference to the particular code in CRA that handles this piece and to share a little of my own insight on the circumstance :p In addition, I've added another potential solution, though it's probably not what you're looking for, it is really my top recommendation.

Comment: This is a good answer, Jonny. For me, the most helpful part is your fourth section, so I would move it to the top. I misunderstood the sentence in the docs --- to me, it sounded like CRA would read an environment variable like PROXY_PORT and PROXY_HOST and use that instead of what is in package.json. Perhaps the original question title was a little ambiguous, but for me, I wasn't looking for a workaround to get environment variables into package.json, but rather to understand whether CRA itself looked at any environment variables, and if not, why the docs seemed to indicate that it did.

Comment: Glad I could help and than you for awarding the bounty! I will make the edit suggested. You are absolutely correct in implying that piece is the real answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set proxy settings in CRA differently than with package.json?

No. It is not possible. Well, at least not yet (2017/01/14).

The React proxy functionality is getting a bit [complicated](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3366) and as a result, the idea of setting up a proxy in a React app from env variables will be implemented as soon the simplification of the ["advanced" proxy configuration](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3366) is finished.

> Is this sentence about proxy or dev server itself?

It Is about the dev server itself. All proxy configuration, as things stand, is configured in package file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think for the second half, the sentence is actually referencing neither the dev server or the proxy server, as explained by @Jonny

Answer (score -1):

You can define env variable for port and host.
 
`REACT_APP_PORT: "PORT of Application", 
REACT_APP_HOST: "host of application"`

To inject all the env to your application you can use [webpack define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

You need to add in plugins section like.

```
const env = require("path to your env file")
//other webpack settings
plugins: {
//plugins
new webpack.DefinePlugin(env)
}
```

Now if you see the [code of create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/2e82ebb3371731a5c4e346f310848ddb23fd0976/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L69) it looks in env variable first to find the `port` and `host`.

Also, note that

> You **MUST** create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name

Comment: How will react know if these `env` variables are for proxying and not for running the app itself?

Comment: This same settings will be used for both.

Comment: What if the client is supposed to run on port 3000 and the server on port 4000? Also, isn't that the use of a proxy; to send requests from clients seeking resources from other servers? Or rather let me ask, why would want to proxy a request that is running in  the same server and port?

Comment: For that case I am using react env variable like REACT_APP_BASE_URL : {server URL} and for all the api I am using like {REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/someapi

Comment: Why do you need a proxy if both the server and the client are running in the same host?

Comment: Thank you for your answer cauchy, but I believe you are misunderstanding the intent of the original question as well as the distinction between setting a host/port for the web server vs. the host/port for the proxy feature.